# 2sxc Create an SQL view of an entity's values

Tags: 2sxc

I'd like to work with data from 2sxc in Excel (for reporting/analysis purposes). Is it possible to create a query that would create a normal looking view with the fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically this can be done using standard sql, but I can't provide a quick example. You basically need to do pivots. Alternately you could create a html-view and open/link that in excel, this is probably much easier to do.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing a bit of both. I grabbed the entity/value data using an SQL statement, and then used Excel's data query to pivot it into a normal excel table. That worked well for me and avoided having to do a dynamic pivot in SQL.